# Change BGM using PlaySound() in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, playsound, winmm

As it is the first time I have ever used this function (I am a very early beginner, started to code in c++ three months ago), I wanted to try it out, with varying degrees of success: basically, my problem is that through my program, I start by using the PlaySound() function like this :
    `PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE1), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);`
    
 
 As you can see, the file is a resource that I have directly included in my project with VS2017. But the problem is not there, as the sound plays fine by itself.

 The problem comes when I try to stop this sound and play another song (also in my project resources). Here is how I did it: 
`PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE1), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
Sleep(2000);
PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE2), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);`

 This is how I tested the what PlaySound works, but it is fundamentally how the playsound fonction is called multiple times in my program. The problem is, when I run this, it compiles, but gives a [memory access violation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFUc2.jpg) (in french, sorry).

 So I tried to first stop the first sound played and then play the second one, like this : 
`PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE1), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
Sleep(2000);
PlaySound(NULL, NULL, SND_ASYNC);
PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE2), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);` 
 but I still got the same error. Finally I messed around and found that adding the SND_NOSTOP flag like this : 
`PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE1), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
Sleep(2000);
PlaySound(NULL, NULL, SND_ASYNC);
PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE2), NULL, SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC | SND_NOSTOP);`
did not cause an error an runs fine, but the second song never plays, and there is just no sound. 
 
 
On a last note I would like to add that I tried swapping IDR_WAVE1 and IDR_WAVE2 and it works just right with songs interchanged so it is (probably ?) not the cause here. 
 Thank you for reading !

**Thanks to @TedLyngmo I read the manual and used the provided examples to a working code :**
`PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE1), GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0);
PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE2), GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_RESOURCE | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC | SND_NOSTOP);`

Comment: I don't think combining `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE2)` and `SND_FILENAME` is correct. When using `SND_FILENAME` I would expect the first parameter to be a path to a file, like `L"C:\\...wav"`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the help, It was a really stupid mistake, but it didn't seem to fix the problem. I edited the post though, thanks !

Comment: The handle shouldn't be `NULL` when playing resources if I read the manual page correctly.

Comment: Looks like you got it working! Great! :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo All thanks to you !

Comment: Generally for high level playback you should use MCI, it provides more controls.